# persist dropdownlist selection located in a control located in a masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have default.aspx used masterpage, in master page i have a control called DefaultMenuContent, this control have a dropdownlist with autopostback, the problem is loosing the selection even if i use Is Not PostBack in control's load event,

every time it's new load, not postback in this scenario!
how to persist the dropdownlist selection?

In Master:

```
                   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MenuContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                          <art:DefaultArabicMenu ID="DefaultMenuContent" runat="server" />
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In Default.aspx

```
Protected Sub ddl_Srv_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddl_Srv.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Bind_List()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to store the selection for the current user's session, you could save the selection in a session variable.

```
Protected Sub dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dropdownlist1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' save selection
    Session("ddl1_selection") = dropdownlist1.SelectedValue

    ' do rest of logic

End Sub
```

In Page Load event check the variable and make the selection

```
 Protected Sub ddl_Srv_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Bind_List()

        If Session("ddl1_selection") IsNot Nothing Then
            dropdownlist1.SelectedValue = Session("ddl1_selection")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, it'll work but i can consider this as a trick, i believe that there is a better solution, it's .NET 4.0!!! do we still need to do this tricks!! anyway i'll consider it as correct answer but hopefully we find better solution soon